# WARNING Compiled with 1 warning in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello hope you are well!

I am creating a crud app in vuejs I  have installed global vuejs, bootstrap and after that import file bootstrap in main.js.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'


Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

But when I run command npm run serve me display error:
WARNING  Compiled with 1 warning                                                                           6:43:27 PM

warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(2482:3) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved by running

```
npm install bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1
```

Comment: for me, solved with `npm install bootstrap@5.2.0`